# Debugging a simple Typescript app in a Browser using VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, visual-studio-code

I am building my first typescript project (my background is C#, Java).The apps works as expected, but i can't put a break point in typescript and debug the application.

Also when i use pure typescript compiler  (tsconfig with tsc.exe) the mapping works perfectly. I am using gulp since i want to bring all js into one file.

When there is a mistake in the generated js, then visual studio code is hitting the break point in js file (bundle.js) instead of typescript, however custom break points never work

I am using windows 10 for development.

Please find my code below.

The HTML

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello World!</title>        
        <!-- <script data-main="main" src="scripts/require.js"></script> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="greeting">Loading ...</p>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Type scripts

**main.ts**

```
import { Student } from "./student";

class Startup {
    public static main(): string {
      return Startup.showHello();
    }

   public static showHello() : string {
     var std = new Student();
      return std.GetText();
    }
}

document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = Startup.main();;
```

**student.ts**

```
export class Student
{
   public GetText() : string
   {
       return "Hi from VB ggggggggggg";
   }
}
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require("gulp");

var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

var browserify = require("browserify");
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var tsify = require("tsify");
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

var paths = {
    pages: ['src/*.html']
};

gulp.task("copy-html", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.pages)
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});

gulp.task("default", ["copy-html"], function () {

    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',
        debug: true,
        entries: ['src/student.ts','src/main.ts'],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
    .plugin(tsify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));  
});
```

**tsconfig.json** (i believe this file is not needed since we use gulp to compile, When using pure typescript compile the break points work as expected)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        // "outFile": "dist/bundle.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

**also launch.js**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/index.html",
           "sourceMaps": true,
           "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/dist",

        },
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
            "type": "edge",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/dist",
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: use the latest version of chrome and you'll be able to debug ts.

Comment: so you using launch with sourcemap options and its still not working?? check if sourcemaps are disabled in chrome settings, plus mostly there is seprate chrome debugger plugin for vscode that you might need to install

Comment: When there is a mistake in the generated js, then visual studio code is hitting the break point in js file (bundle.js) instead of typescript, however custom break points never work

Comment: I have already installed the plugin, that's is what launching chrome when I hit play